# Crystal Reports - Running Total is duplicating if a group has more than 1 "detail"

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that I am trying to get working in Crystal. Basically the report is about gifts (I work for a non-profit). I grouped the report by Payment Method, and then Gift ID, which is a unique field in the .MDB file used to fuel the report.

I want to keep gifts with the same payment method together, which is why I first grouped by that. Then I grouped by Gift ID. the "Details" of my report is a field called Soft Credit Donor, which will list out as many donors that were given soft credit on the gift. There could be 0, there could be multiple...I show running totals in the Report Footer. I have a Gift Count (a Distinct Count of Gift ID, evaluating on each record, resetting Never), a Sum of all Gifts (a sum of Gift Amount, evaluating on Change of Field - Gift ID, resetting Never). These 2 fields work fine.

Then I get to where I want a running total based on each Payment Method. I am able to easily show the # of gifts per payment method. I do this with 4 separate running total fields (one for each payment method). I am doing a Distinct Count on GIft ID, evaluating on a formula (payment_method = "Business Check", "Personal Check", "Credit Card", etc...and Resetting Never.

My issue is when I try to do a $$ total for each payment method. In this case I am seeing that my running total is duplicating if there is more than 1 "detail" or soft credit donor. My running total field is doing a sum of the Gift Amount field, evaluating on a formula (payment_method = "business check", etc...), and I've played around with the Resetting. If I choose Resetting Never, then I am seeing the money being double or triple, etc...counted. Depending on if  gift has more than 1 "detail". If I choose to reset on change of field and I set that to either Payment_Method or GiftID, I get a blank running total.

One thing to mention is that my MDB file has multiple tables that are all left outer joined to the main table which holds the Gift ID and Payment method fields. So there is a Soft_Credit table that holds the Gift ID field, along with the each name of the Donor who gets a soft credit. I'm not sure if that matters or not.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in a formula:

`If {payment_method} = "Credit Card" Then 1 Else 0`

Use this formula as sum in the running total.
Use "on change" on the id field.
User "never reset" for the total sum.

You have to create one formula and one running total for each payment method.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it worked like a charm.